# Swift Array(bufferPointer) EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: swift, pointers, audio, crash, buffer

I am receiving audio buffers and I am converting them into a conventional array for ease of use. This code has always been reliable. However, recently it began crashing quite frequently. I am using Airpods when it crashes, which may or may not be part of the problem. The mic object is an AKMicrophone object from AudioKit.

```
func tap(){
        let recordingFormat = mic.outputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        mic.outputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        mic.outputNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
                                  bufferSize: UInt32(recordingBufferSize),
                                  format: recordingFormat)
        { (buffer, when) in
            let stereoDataUnsafePointer = buffer.floatChannelData!
            let monoPointer = stereoDataUnsafePointer.pointee
            let count = self.recordingBufferSize
            let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: monoPointer, count: count)
            let array = Array(bufferPointer) //CRASHES HERE
        }
        mic.start()
    }
```

When running on iPhone 7 with airpods, this crashes about 7/10 times with one of two different error messages:
 EXC_BAD_ACCESS
 Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range

If the way I was converting the array was wrong I would expect it to crash every time. I speculate that the recording sample rate could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I hardcoded the buffer size to 10000, and when initiating the tap, specified buffer size of 10000. However, the device ignored this buffer size and instead sent me buffers that were 6400. This meant when I tried to initialize an array of with size 10000 it went off the end. I modified code to check the actual buffer size, not the size I requested:

```
let stereoDataUnsafePointer = buffer.floatChannelData!
            let monoPointer = stereoDataUnsafePointer.pointee
            let count = buffer.frameLength //<--Check actual buffer size
            let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: monoPointer, count: Int(count))
            let array = Array(bufferPointer)
```